# Using Strings to Import .dat Column Lists to Form Multiple Arrays

Tags: python, arrays, string

I have a file of .dat files each titled "Dk_LCDM_z" each with a suffix corresponding to values of z as shown in my code. Each of these files has 3 columns and I would like to import each column.

In other words for each value of z, I would like to import a 50(?)x3 matrix each of which is from a different .dat file.

I don't have a huge amount of experience in Python and have already attempted to use both np.genfromtxt and importlib to no avail.

```
z  = [0,0.25,0.5,0.75,1,1.25,1.5,1.75,2,2.25,2.5,2.75,3,3.25,3.5,3.75,4]
```

Apologies for the lack of code, as I have already deleted/overwritten older versions where I attempted the solution.

The .dat files I have look something like this, but for many more rows.

```
0.100000E-03    0.248466E-10    0.248466E-10
0.102016E-03    0.268944E-10    0.268944E-10
0.104072E-03    0.291109E-10    0.291109E-10
0.106170E-03    0.315101E-10    0.315101E-10
0.108311E-03    0.341071E-10    0.341071E-10
0.110494E-03    0.369181E-10    0.369180E-10
0.112721E-03    0.399607E-10    0.399607E-10
0.114994E-03    0.432540E-10    0.432540E-10
0.117312E-03    0.468188E-10    0.468188E-10
```

And I would like to be able to call values from the second and third columns independently, as they both depend on the first column and z respectively. I'm not sure how best to do this though.

Comment: Consider posting sample `.dat` file, desired output, and some code; `importlib` is a library for importing Python modules, not data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To load the data you need to iterate through your `z` list, generate a file name from each value and then get that files' contents which is fairly straight forward. The real kicker is what you want to do with the data afterwards because dependent on that the actual data parsing/loading may differ significantly.

Since you haven't specified a use case, here's how you can make a generalized solution:

```
z = [0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1, 1.25, 1.5, 1.75, 2, 2.25, 2.5, 2.75, 3, 3.25, 3.5, 3.75, 4]

data_map = {}  # we'll use a dictionary to store our data for fast lookups
for e in z:  # loop through all elements of z
    with open("Dk_LCDM_{}.dat".format(e), "r") as f:  # open each file
        # iterate over each line, split on whitespace and convert each entry to Python float
        data_map[e] = [[float(x) for x in line.split()] for line in f]
```

Then you can access the second value of the third row of a file corresponding to your fourth `z` element (e.g. `Dk_LCDM_0.75.dat`) as: `data_map[z[3]][2][1]` or literally as `data_map[0.75][2][1]`

**EDIT** - You can transpose the generated list of rows into a list of columns by parsing the files like:

```
data_map[e] = [col for col in zip(*[[float(x) for x in line.split()] for line in f])]
```

Then you can access the fourth row, of the third column of the second file as: `data_map[0.25][2][3]` and you can get the whole second column of the third file as: `data_map[0.5][1]`.

Comment: Thank you! Would there also be any way to call a whole column? (e.g. data_map[0.75][col2][1]) Or even assigning a whole column to a variable: i.e. col1 = k, col2=lnD, col3=nlnD